# Do not collect child opentelemetry trace when parent trace is not recorded

Tags: c#, .net, open-telemetry

I'm in the middle of introducing distributed tracing in a microservice app. All my services have the tracing enabled and everything works fine. But...
My app runs on a K8S cluster, so that cluster makes a lot of call to health endpoint. A lot is a lot. for the moment when nothing happens on a setup, I get 50Gb of trace recorder per day.
trace lock like this: one trace for the /health call and one children trace for a database call (call to check if db is available)
So, i decided to not record Health trace this is easily done by

```
// in startup
tracerProviderBuilder.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(x => x.Filter = AspnetCoreOtelFilter.Filter)

//the filter
public static class AspnetCoreOtelFilter
{
  public static bool Filter(HttpContext httpContext)
  {
    if (httpContext.Request.Path == "/health/liveness")
      return false;
    if (httpContext.Request.Path == "/health/readiness")
      return false;

    return true;
  }
}
```

as a result, I don't see all the health trace in my APM, anymore, but I keep receiving the trace regarding the log in DB

I was expecting that ParentBasedSampler (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry/Trace/ParentBasedSampler.cs) would do the magic, but it's not the case.

Do you have any idea.

Thx for your help

Here is my test class:

```
[TestMethod, Ignore("Didn't succeed to avoid child message for now")]
  public async Task HealthWithSubTrace_NoTracing()
  {
    var exportedItems = new List<Activity>();

    var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();

    using (var client = factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
      builder.ConfigureTestServices(serviceCollection => ConfigureInMemoryExporterForOpenTelemetry()).CreateClient())
    {
      using var response = await client.GetAsync((string?)"/health/details").ConfigureAwait(false);
      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

      WaitForActivityExport(exportedItems, 1);
    }

    Assert.AreEqual(0, exportedItems.Count);
  }

//OTEL configuration is this
tracerProviderBuilder
      .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
        .AddService(serviceName))
      .SetSampler(sp => new ParentBasedSampler(new  AlwaysOnSampler())
      .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(x => x.Filter = AspnetCoreOtelFilter.Filter)
      .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
      .AddProcessor<K8STagsProcessor>()
      .AddSource(OpenTelemetrySources.Npgsql)
      .AddSource(Program.source.Name);

//with program defined as this
public class Program
{
  public static readonly ActivitySource source = new("OpenTelemtry.Test.App");
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Services.ConfigurePhoenixHealth()
      .AddHealthChecks().AddCheck(HealthConstants.Self, () => HealthCheckResult.Healthy());

    var app = builder.Build();
    app.UsePhoenixHealth();

    app.MapGet("/health/details", () =>
    {
      using var activity = source.StartActivity("health.detail");
      return "all fine";
    });

    app.Run();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you put a reproducible app together somewhere (GitHub for ex)? I tried with a sample app I have, filtering out an endpoint that has further down calls that are instrumented (db, etc) and none of those child spans are there. BTW the default sampler is the ParentBase one, as stated in the OTel SDK spec: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/trace/sdk.md#built-in-samplers

Answer (score 0):

I did use a BaseProcessor instead that does the work fine.

```
public class ActivityFilterProcessor : BaseProcessor<Activity> 
{  
 private readonly List<string> _routes = new() { "health", "metrics" };

 public ActivityFilterProcessor(OpenTelemetryConfigurationMonitor OpenTelemetryConfiguration, ILogger<ActivityFilterProcessor> logger) => _logger = logger;

public override void OnEnd(Activity activity)   
{
 try
 {
  if (activity.Status == ActivityStatusCode.Error)
   return;
  var route = activity.Tags.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == TraceSemanticConventions.AttributeHttpTarget);
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(route.Key) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(route.Value) && _routes.Any(q => route.Value.Contains(q)))
   activity.ActivityTraceFlags &= ~ActivityTraceFlags.Recorded;
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
   //manage exception
 }
}
```

}

that I use with the tracerProviderBuilder like this

`tracerProviderBuilder.AddProcessor<ActivityFilterProcessor>()`